# Selector don't getting notification from NSNotificationCenter (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

I am sending a notification from a class inherits from NSObject using NSNotificationCenter.

The notification should be sent to 2 viewController but it's being sent just to one of them.

My Code:

**fetchFromParse**:

```
-(void)sendAllStores
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"getStoresArrays" object:nil userInfo:self.storesDict];
}
```

**firstVC.m** (working):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(getStoresArrays:) name:@"getStoresArrays" object:nil];
}

-(void)getStoresArrays:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@“Working”); //Working   
}
```

**secondVC.m** (not working):

```
-(void)prepareArrays
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(getStoresArrays:) name:@"getStoresArrays" object:nil];
}
-(void)getStoresArrays:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@“Not Working”); //Not working
}
```

**AppDelegate.m**:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    secondVC *secVC=[[secondVC alloc] init];
    [secVC prepareArrays];

    fetchFromParse *fetchFromParseObj=[[fetchFromParse alloc] init];
    [fetchFromParseObj getStoresFromParse];

    Return YES;
}
```

Note: Xcode shows me an error message that "firstVC is not registered as an observer".

Comment: is viewDidLoad of firstVC being called?

Comment: @User31 Yes, the notification is being sent to firstVC as well, the problem is secondVC.

Comment: Do you remove observer from firstVC ?

Comment: @User31 No, I don't.

Comment: You should remove observer from both controllers

Comment: Updated the post with a note

Comment: put a breakpoint at viewDidLoad on firstVC and check if it is being called before the getStoresArrays method of firstVC.

Comment: @User31 It is (firstVC's viewDidLoad is being called before getStoresArrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic for your code is not correct. You are posting a notification and have made two classes as observer, so this will lead to unpredictable results. You should have one class as observer for a notification.

Answer (score 2):

The firstVC is never used so it cannot add an observer then.

It adds the observer in the viewDidLoad, but if the view controller is never used it cannot load a view and therefore not add an observer.

Comment: It works on the first VC, I don't work on the secondVC. BTW, The firstVC is being used using storyboard.

Comment: I don't think the way you implemented it works that way. Another solution is to not use NSNotification (It's possible to, but I don't see a reason why yet.) and create a base class where the firstVC and secondVC inherit from and create a method in that base class that'll fetch the data from Parse and access that method in the viewWillAppear / viewDidLoad in the firstVC / secondVC.

Comment: I prefer using NSNotificationCenter, but why doesn't it work??

Comment: I honestly don't know why it doesn't work, hence I'm against using it in this case. If you're set on using NSNotificationCenter, then I would place it in a super class for both controllers. It's important to know that from what I see in your code. If you're transitioning to the secondVC from the firstVC you will also not receive a notification, because 1. prepareArrays is not called when secondVC is loaded and 2. in the AppDelegate you just initialized the secondVC and called the method. You will not hold reference to the secondVC any longer if didFinish method is done. Maybe that's the case?

Comment: So you suggest to call `prepareArrays` on secondVC's `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Not only that. What I would do is like I said before create a base view controller and call [fetchFromParseObj getStoresFromParse] in the viewWillAppear.

Comment: firstVC is what the user sees and secondVC is just in the background (for handling CLLocationManagerDelegate) and the user don't see it. They are really different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see only one notification listener should be called here and that should be your SecondVC because your first view controller is not loaded yet so no observer is registered for first view controller.

Comment: The opposite, the firstVC works and the secondVC doesn't

Comment: @FS.O not sure why it works because as per the code your second controller notification observer is attached before posting a notification but your firstVC should not have a observer attached for notification because initial view controller is loaded after AppDelegate. So only secondVC should get your notification.